# Getter does not update when route param updates

Tags: vuejs3, pinax

I have a vue3 app that has a parameterized route and a Pina store getter that gets a list of items based on the route param.

My issue is that my list of values from the store (gotten via a getter) does not get re-gotten when the route param is updated.

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import {useIncStore} from "@/store/inc";
  import {useRoute} from "vue-router";

  const route = useRoute()
  const state = Array.isArray(route.params.state) ? route.params.state[0] : route.params.state
  const incStore = useIncStore();

  // EDIT - Neither of these work...
  const incs = incStore.getByState(state)
  // const incs = computed(() => incStore.getByState(state))

</script>
```

How can I call `incStore.getByState(state)` again when `state` updates? If I put `{{state}}` on my page it updates when the route changes but my list of items does not.

Here is my getter in the store:

```
  getters: {
    getByState(state) {
      return (s: string) => state.records.filter((rec: any) => rec.state === s)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Tried that too and no joy

Comment: This is not a good getter. Remove this getter from the store and instead convert it to a computed property in your component which will react to the route param. If you want to continue using the current getter - you will have to call it every time the route param changes. So you will need a watcher for the route param.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the getter returning a function. What's not wright here is the param passed. I don't think it's a string, but a ref containing a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I'd post my answer, as the comments above said I had to use computed properties to react to both the route change and then the changed route value.

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import useIncStore from "@/store/inc";
import {useRoute} from "vue-router";
import {computed} from "vue";

const route = useRoute()
const incStore = useIncStore();
const state = computed({
  get() {
    return Array.isArray(route.params.state) ? route.params.state[0] : route.params.state
  },
  set() {
  }
})

const incs = computed({
  get() {
    return incStore.getByState(state.value)
  },
  set() {
  }
})
</script>
```